# How can one consolidate a number of .git folders & corresponding remote repositories into one super repository?

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to consolidate about 15 local git folders (with subfolders & files) / 15 repositories into 1 super folder / 1 super repository while maintaining each local folders git history and relationship to its respective repository (to become a sub folder on git).

Is this possible? What are the steps one would need to take to make it happen?

Comment: What effect do you want combining them to have?  Do they have many files in common, and the potential space savings are getting to be worth some pain, or ... ?

Comment: Main purpose this time around was to merely clean up and organize repos. The individual repos have a common thread but they are not inter-related for functionality. Like an Archive of all the exercises from a book.

Comment: It seems to me you're trying to force an abstract simplicity that doesn't exist in reality, then.  I don't remember that ever turning out well for me.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a [Git submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) approach.

First, just create a simple git repository. Then, add each git folder you want to consolidate using the following command (from the main repo root):

```
git submodule add repo_url local_path
```

Each *git submodule* will kept its own history.

Comment: Note that git submodules are designed for local snapshots at given commits of repositories, and are somewhat cumbersome to work with if you need to follow development in the original repositories.

Comment: You're right, but I don't see an other way to do it. Nothing prevent him to add repositories with write access to directly work in it.

Comment: @abeaumet- I've been experimenting with the submodule idea but doesn't seem to be working quite yet. Need to patiently experiment & figure out the steps to make it all work. Thanks for pointing me in the direction and the documentation link.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - good to know the complexity regarding submodules when working with original repositories. Helps decide what to move now and what to move later. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the [repo](http://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html) tool that is used in Android development. The android source tree consists of many git repositories tied together using repo. It may be tricky to find out how to configure the repo XML configuration file but the Android tree should provide a useful example.

Comment: Thanks! Comparisons/examples help. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You could combine all those repositories into a single one by having separate sets of independent branches for each one. This would also mean that you would share the same object database for all repositories, which removes redundancy. But it would also mean that you cannot really work with a single subrepository alone without taking the rest of the big one as well.

Note that in general, it is recommended to keep the repositories separate. It’s not really a problem either. The best example is GitHub’s Gist where they have separate repositories for *each* Gist although most of them just contain a single file.

So don’t spend time trying to combine those (probably not that related) repositories; just use them separately.

Comment: That makes sense. This was a part of cleanup attempt. Using other good practices - like naming convention, project descriptions, readme, urls etc.. to keep the account clean and restore sanity.